# Replacing specific number of whitespace characters in strings

Tags: c#, .net

I have strings that looks like this,

```
"ad hominem  ",
"ad lib  ",
"ad lib  ",
"adamantine  ",
"adamite     ",
"adder   ",
"Addisonian  ",
"addlepated  ",
"adduce  ",
```

so basically what i want to do is in the cases where there is more than one character of whitespace (meaning its not two words ), get rid of it, so the lust looks like this

```
"ad hominem",
"ad lib",
"ad lib",
"adamantine",
"adamite",
"adder",
"Addisonian",
"addlepated",
"adduce",
```

this is what I tried:

```
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb,"  ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb,"  ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "   ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "   ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "   ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "   ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "      ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "       ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "        ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "         ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "          ", ""));
sb = (Regex.Replace(sb, "           ", ""));
```

*edit Trim() won't work because the whitespaces are not at the end or beginning.

Comment: You can use stringvar.trim()???

Comment: This is a basic usage of the string object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

Comment: @Vijay nope, because the whitespaces are not at the end or beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a regex, you could do a

```
sb = Regex.Replace(sb, @"\s{2,}", " ");
```

to replace all consecutive whitespaces anywhere within the string with a single space. Follow this by a `.Trim()` to get rid of spaces at the start or end.

Answer (score 2):

If all the words are as written, then you could just use `TrimEnd(' ')`.

Answer (score 1):

String.Trim() will return the value without the extra whitespace at the start or end of the string.

For more specifics take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trim() function. It will trim the whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

just use `sb.trim();`, this will remove whitespaces from both ends.

Comment: .NET uses Pascal Case naming convention thus `Trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Trim() method to remove all the leading and tailing white spaces.